# Pandas: get average over certain rows and return as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this

[image]

It contains `speed` and `dir` at different date's hour minute. For example, the first row records that at 7:11, 20060101, the `dir=87, speed=5`.

Now, I think the data might be too precise, and I want to use the **average at each hour** for later computation. How can I do it?

---

I can do it by `groupy`

```
df['Hr']=df['HrMn'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-2])
df.groupby(['date', 'Hr'])['speed'].mean()
```

which would return what I want

[image]

But it is not a dataframe, and how can I use for later computation? Specifically, I want to know

1. If the `groupby` approach I'm using is the right approach for this problem? If so, how to use it later as a dataframe? (I also need to get `dir`, `dir_max` and other attributes as well)
2. The result `groupby` return is not well-orderd (in `date` and `Hr`), is there anyway to re-order it?

---

Update:

If I do `df.groupby(['date', 'Hr'])['speed'].mean().unstack()`, it would return

[image]

The data is certainly correct, but I still want to it follow the initial dataframe form as

[image]

Except that `HrMn` -> `Hr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is a multi-index dataframe. you can try

```
df.groupby(['date', 'Hr'])['speed'].mean().reset_index()
```

If you want mean for rest of the data, try

```
df.groupby(['date', 'Hr'])['speed', 'dir_max', 'speed_max'].mean().reset_index()
```

EDIT:
Applying mean on speed column and max on dir_max and speed_max

```
df.groupby(['date', 'Hr']).agg({'speed' : np.mean,'dir_max' : np.max, 'speed_max': np.max}).reset_index()
```

Comment: This is what I want, but how do I re-order. and for `dir_max` and `speed_max`, I need `df.groupby(['date', 'Hr'])['dir_max', 'speed_max'].max()`, I might need to create 2 df and then merge them?